# Programmatically put activity indicator on the login button

Tags: authentication, uibutton, spinner, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to programmatically place an activity indicator on the login button. At the moment, my button looks like this:

[image]

How can I place an activity indicator on the left side of the Login text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a specific framework you are trying to use here, but here is a basic fiddle with possibly what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/mqFQg/

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIProgressView and just overlay it on the button. Nothing fancy ;)